# Columns of two dinamically added TableRow have same width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm writing an app who read a sqlite DB through a query and compile a Table with the results adding dinamically a TableRow layout for every row the query return.

Currently I've got two tables, one for fixed header and horizontal scrolling purposes and one for the results.
But the columns of the two doesn't have the same width.
Logical solution it's to get the width of a column from the header and the width from the result and set the lower value to the value of the other.
But my code doesn't work as expected.

How is possible to set the column witdh?

Here's my code:

```
final int[] maxLarg = new int[4];
final TableRow testata = findViewById(R.id.testRigaTabOrdini);
final TableRow dettagli = findViewById(R.id.dettRigaTabOrdini);
final TextView testCodCli = testata.findViewById(R.id.testCodice);
final TextView testRagSoc = testata.findViewById(R.id.testRagSoc);
final TextView testDataDoc = testata.findViewById(R.id.testData);
final TextView testImporto = testata.findViewById(R.id.testImporto);

final TextView codCli = dettagli.findViewById(R.id.dettCodCli);
final TextView ragSoc = dettagli.findViewById(R.id.dettRagSoc);
final TextView dataDoc = dettagli.findViewById(R.id.dettDataDoc);
final TextView importo = dettagli.findViewById(R.id.dettImporto);
final int[] lungh = new int[4];

testata.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        maxLarg[0] = testCodCli.getWidth();
        maxLarg[1] = testRagSoc.getWidth();
        maxLarg[2] = testDataDoc.getWidth();
        maxLarg[3] = testImporto.getWidth();
            testata.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });

dettagli.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        lungh[0] = codCli.getWidth();
        lungh[1] = ragSoc.getWidth();
        lungh[2] = dataDoc.getWidth();
        lungh[3] = importo.getWidth();

            dettagli.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });

    ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener drawListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw() {
            for (int i = 0; lungh.length > i;){
                if (lungh[i] > maxLarg[i]){
                    switch (i){
                        case 0:
                            codCli.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            testCodCli.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ragSoc.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            testRagSoc.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dataDoc.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            testDataDoc.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            importo.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            testImporto.setWidth(lungh[i]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    switch (i){
                        case 0:
                            codCli.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            testCodCli.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ragSoc.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            testRagSoc.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dataDoc.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            testDataDoc.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            importo.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            testImporto.setWidth(maxLarg[i]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    };

    dettagli.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(drawListener);
    dettagli.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnDrawListener(drawListener);
}
```